# How to get the name from id which is passed in url and as hidden value to another to the another form in view in blade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, url, laravel-blade

I am facing an error , say I have form assign role to user , I have got the user_id as in input value and the in the url like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Admin/9/AssignRole/add , here 9 stands for user_id, now the main problem is here I have form which is like below:: [image]

as you can see here I have user name which is disabled , here I have to show the name of user whose current id is passed it the url..
now thing is that how to do that ?? tried many solutions but nothing worked??
help plz

here is the function of add in controller

```
       public function add($user_id,Request $request)
 {

    //  here by using this we can get id which is present in url
    $User_id = $request->route('user_id');
    
    
    $Role = role::get();
    
     return view('AssignRole.add',compact('User_id','Role'));
 }
```

and blade file code:

```
      <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" value="" name="rolename" readonly>
        </div>
```

as below answer suggested tried dd($user);
getting this output :
[image]

```
App\Models\User {#334
    #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "name",
        1 => "email",
        2 => "password"
    ],
    #hidden: array:2 [
        0 => "password",
        1 => "remember_token"
    ],
    #casts: array:1 [
        "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
    ],
    #connection: null,
    #table: null,
    #primarykey: "id",
    #key Type: "int",
    +incrementing: true,
    #with: [],
    #withCount: [],
    +preventsLazyLoading: false,
    #perPage: 15
    -exists: false,
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false,
    #attributes: 1,
    #original: [],
    #changes: [],
    #classCastCache: [],
    #dates: [],
    #dateFormat: null,
    #appends: [],
    #dispatchesEvents: [],
    #observables: [],
    #relations: [],
    #touches: [],
    +timestamps: true,
    #visible: [],
    #guarded: array:1 [
        '*'
        
    ]
    #rememberTokenName: "remember_token",
}
```

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68223175/edit) the code of your tries to your question?

Comment: which code are you talking about controller or view ?? ok .let me add code of both

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container) and Laravel's [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding):

```
public function add(User $user)
 {    
    $Role = role::get();
    
     return view('AssignRole.add',compact('user','Role'));
 }
```

Comment: thanks mate , but how to use it in blade file

Comment: as `{{ $user->name }}` or however the property's name is

Comment: no  brother same error .. and one question why u removed request and $user_id in function ..and this is in rolesuer controller

Comment: Because you don't need it. The `{{user}}` from URL is already resolved to `User` model via service container.

Comment: Can you `dd($user);` above the `return` and tell me the result?

Comment: you can't have that error since `dd()` stops the script executing before the blade view is accessed.

Comment: i am sorry , means in dd all other columns are visible , but not name

Comment: Which other columns? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68223175/edit) them to your question?

Comment: added check again @shaedrich

Comment: According to the output of `dd`, it should have `name`, but `exists` is `false` - are you sure, a user with id 9 exists in your database?

Comment: the user 9 has been deleted , i am doing this with user_id  =1

Comment: if your `dd()`'s result is the model instance in the question, then it indicates that user 1 doesn't exist either.

Comment: same error getting while accessing other users also